# What is effective Xmx value on my redhat machine running tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, redhat, heap-memory

I am running tomcat on RHEL 7 machine with 1GB RAM. I have setup tomcat and java both to have Xmx=1G and below statements support that,

> [root@ip-172-31-28-199 bin]# java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep
>   HeapSize Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1g
>       uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                                   {product}
>       uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
>       uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 16777216                            {product}
>       uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
>       uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 1073741824                          {product} openjdk version "1.8.0_161"

and

> tomcat    2799     1  1 02:21 ?        00:00:07 /usr/bin/java
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Xmx1024M -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

But when I get exception, I get following message,

> ## There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
>
> ## Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 244043776 bytes for committing reserved memory.

I know java can never claim 1GB memory as that is the total memory of the machine. but why I am getting error with this size mentioned?

Comment: That's a logic problem. If your server has only 1GB RAM, why do you think you should reserve 1GB RAM for Tomcat? OS and other software need to use system memory as well! You'd better increase your server memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-Xms1g` too, so it initially allocates all the memory, and you'll find that it cannot even start Tomcat.

If you want to squeeze as much memory into Tomcat as possible *(not recommended)*, slowly reduce both numbers (same value for `mx` and `ms`) until Tomcat starts.

That is the absolute maximum you can give Tomcat, but you shouldn't do that. Java may still need more as it runs, and the OS will need more occasionally, so you should give Tomcat less than that absolute maximum.

Now that you've found the number, you can leave `-Xms` undefined again, if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting post [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187709) that suggests disabling OOPS.
Are you running a physical server or a VM ?

I agree a 1G server is under-sized, you should run Xmx=512M and allow some swappiness (vm.swappiness = 60 is the default, which should be OK for a small Tomcat)